# Find mean, standard deviation etc of azimuths

Tags: matlab, angle, polar-coordinates, azimuth

I have a Matlab script that tells me about great circle paths crossing grid locations, and want to look at the distribution of paths crossing a certain grid location.  For some location, I have a vector of azimuths of paths crossing that location,

```
az_vec
```

and I want to find the mean, standard deviation, and potentially other quantities of this vector.  What I have right now is simply

```
mean_az = mean(az_vec);
std_az  = std(az_vec);
```

and these work fine for narrow distributions of angles far away from 0/360 degrees, but for distributions including 0 degrees they don't work.  E.g.

```
mean_az = mean([10 350])
```

should return 0, not 180.  I don't think I can use a function like wrapTo180, because then I will have the same problem around 180 degrees.

Is there some way to handle this wrapping problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in the MATLAB file exchange for this:

[MEANANGLE](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12631-mean-angle)

```
>> meanangle([10,340])

ans =

   -5.0000
```